# How to append DateTime to a ConsoleTextBox?

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox, console

I created a Textbox according to [this tutorial](http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/). Its purpose is to display everything that is written to Console. Here the class:

```
 public class TextBoxConsole : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox output = null; //Textbox used to show Console's output.  

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom TextBox-Class used to print the Console output. It also saves the output to a *.txt-File on the Desktop.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_output">Textbox used to show Console's output.</param>
        public TextBoxConsole(TextBox _output) 
        {
            output = _output;
            output.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
            output.WordWrap = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends text to the textbox and to the logfile
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Input-string which is appended to the textbox and logfile.</param>
        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            output.AppendText(value.ToString());//Append char to the textbox
        }


        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I Initialize the "Console":

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();        
    writer = new TextBoxConsole(tbConsole);
    Console.SetOut(writer);
}
```

Now I want to add current time in front of every statement that would have been written to the console. I can not implement this directly in the `Write(char value)`-method because this would append time before every single character. Is there any solution without writing time into every `Console.WriteLine()` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra overload to `TextBoxConsole`

```
public override void Write(String value)
{
    base.Write(value);
    output.AppendText(value);
}
```

Then you can directly call the

```
InitializeComponent();        
writer = new TextBoxConsole(tbConsole);
Console.SetOut(writer);
writer.Write("DATE_TIME_FORMATTED_AS_STRING");
```

Comment: This makes sence but how would I call this overload? It seems Console.Write() still calls the Write(char value)-method.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this completely but it should put you in the right direction.

Under the events in the properties window for the text box generate an event for KeyPress.

```
private void txtConsole_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // checks if the last key that was pressed was the enter key
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            // once the user presses enter write the date
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```